# Can I add and remove Jitsi Meet pre-build functionalities?

Tags: flutter, firebase, jitsi-meet

I am using Jitsi Meet for my Video Conferencing App using Flutter + Firebase.

I want to know can I add and remove it's pre-build functionalities?

For Example:
I want to use only Video Call and Audio feature from Jitsi Meet but I also need Chat, Raise Hand, Screen Sharing etc features.

So can I add those features by myself after removing/disabling pre-build features in Jitsi Meet?

I tried disabling its features and fortunately now its not displaying in my app, only video call and audio features are there.

Now I want to add chat, screen sharing etc features by myself in Jisti Meet.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem, otherwise this is not a programming problem but a software usage one. Let S.O. know how you are trying to perform the configuration code and what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Jitsi-meet version. If you customized from older branch, the configuration of whether to enable/disable features can be set in interface_config.js.
During the development of Jitsi-meet, several features have been moved to config.js slowly. For example:

```
// interface_config.js
// This config was moved to config.js as `toolbarButtons`.
// TOOLBAR_BUTTONS: [],

// config.js
toolbarButtons: [
   'camera',
   //'chat',
   //'closedcaptions',
   'desktop',
   'download',
   //'embedmeeting',
   //'etherpad',
   'feedback',
   'filmstrip',
   'fullscreen',
   'hangup',
   'help',
   'invite',
   //'livestreaming',
   'microphone',
   'mute-everyone',
   'mute-video-everyone',
   'participants-pane',
   'profile',
   'raisehand',
   'recording',
   'security',
   'select-background',
   'settings',
   //'shareaudio',
   //'sharedvideo',
   'shortcuts',
   //'stats',
   'tileview',
   'toggle-camera',
   'videoquality',
   '__end'
]
```